# Как обрабатывать php скрипт по времени?

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим файл лежит на хостинге (в моем случае локалхост).
Мне необходимо, чтобы скрипт, который там находится обрабатывался каждый день в 6 вечера.

В скрипте смс-рассылка. Тексты и номера берутся из постоянно обновляющейся БД, поэтому скрипт обрабатывает разные сообщения.

Как этого добиться?

Comment: оффтоп: а как смс рассылаете?

Comment: платный шлюз.

Answer (score 5):

В общем тут вариант очень простой если у вас windows можно пользоваться либо стандартным планировщиком задач либо [развернуть cron](http://habrahabr.ru/post/149545/).
В линукс есть `cron` настраивайте свой скрипт и рассылайте: [Планировщик Linux (cron, crontab, anacron)](http://www.k-max.name/linux/planirovshhik-linux-cron-crontab-anacron/)

Answer (score 3):

Прочитайте про [cron](http://masterhost.ru/support/doc/cron/). Он для этого и сделан.

> В ОС Unix существует возможность запускать программы пользователя в указанное им время. Для этого используется программа cron, которая получает инструкции от пользователей и следуя им производит выполнение любых задач по полученным сценариям. Наши клиенты могут пользоваться данной возможностью для выполнения периодических задач.